# Which countries other than China deport illegal North Korean immigrants back to North Korea?

Tags: north-korea

> The Chinese government routinely labels North Koreans as illegal
> “economic migrants” and forcibly repatriates them under a 1986
> bilateral border protocol. But as a party to the 1951 Refugee
> Convention and its 1967 Protocol, and the UN Convention against
> Torture, China is obligated not to force back anyone who would be at
> risk of persecution or torture upon return.
>
> North Korean authorities consider departures from the country without
> permission a serious crime. Since anyone who returns to North Korea
> after fleeing will likely be tortured or otherwise mistreated, all
> have a claim for refugee status in whichever country they reach.

https://www.hrw.org/news/2021/07/22/china-restarts-forced-returns-refugees-north-korea

I am wondering if there's any other countries other than China that does the same thing. I am guessing Russia does it, but I am wondering if there are other countries that might do the same despite the way the North Korean government treat defectors.

Comment: Well, only China, South Korea, and Russia have a border with North Korea. South Korea is more likely to see defection as a victory for them, and you already mentioned the other two. Any other country would be unlikely to have any North Korean immigrants who entered illegally.

Comment: @Obie2.0 someone fleeing North Korea via China would not be safe there so they'd have to keep going until they arrive somewhere that allows them to travel freely. I think a common route aims for the South Korean embassy in Thailand where they can claim asylum for South Korea and then fly there without interference from local authorities. Getting that far isn't easy and requires passing through multiple countries. (I don't have a souce handy for this right now but the question makes more sense with this consideration)